# where to put htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the phpMyDataGird script to edit MySQL database tables through the web without using phpMyAdmin (I just use phpMyAdmin to manage the values but this script to manage the data)

The problem comes when I add HTML to a field. I want to be able to see them as code and not let them transform.

This is an example of how the [script](http://leb-media.com/fouadlb/files/GermanySupporters/Scores2/phpmydatagrid-2011-09-27/sample9.php) looks. If you click on a field you'll be able to edit it. In the first row, second column I wrote `<i><b>someone</b></i>` and as you can see it's not showing the code but is being bolded and italicized.

This is the [main page](http://pastebin.com/44qgpeti) of the script where I add my MySQL information and change settings, and this main page is connected to a [page](http://pastebin.com/LqavqHdx) where all the script is written.

Can anyone take a look at these pages and tell me where to add the `htmlspecialchars()` call because I have been trying, but it's not working.

Comment: i did post links for the words "Script" (an exampel) "Main Page" and "Page" ( the script page)
Thanks :)!

Comment: For future reference your links may not work anymore so please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. i thought would be better to add it on pastebin because its kinda big :)

Comment: @Meh: Don't *link* to your code, inline it. Your question will be worthless once your links go down, and we don't want this to happen, do we? Also, don't pastebin it, extract the relevant portions of code, and include these only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to show the HTML special chars only in the grid (and they can stay as they are) try to edit the line 1612 in a 'page' script - that should be a `mask` function:

```
        function mask($value,$mask,$datatype,$aselect,$row){
            switch ($datatype){
                    ...
                    default:               
/*1612 line here --> */ return htmlspecialchars($value);
            }
        }
```

But I'm not sure if this is what You want to achieve...

EDIT: to also save the data in htmlspecialchar formatted value, try to change the line 927 from

```
$strUpdate = "UPDATE $this->tablename set $value=".magic_quote($nt)." $updWhere Limit 1";
```

to

```
$strUpdate = "UPDATE $this->tablename set $value=".htmlspecialchars(magic_quote($nt))." $updWhere Limit 1";
```

but again, I'm not sure... If this is OK, then You can remove the htmlspecialchars in previous example (line 1612).

Comment: it worked thanks, but after i edit and hit enter its being transformed again, but if i refresh the page it goes back to code... is there anywhere else we could add this code in ? :), Thanks again for ur help!

Comment: it didn't work, this code is now saving the html codes as `&lt;B&gt;`..
Anyway the first code fixed my problem it's okay :)
But i have a question if u can help me... when i try add html code as `<td id='ab'>text</td>` .. its being written in the database as `<td id=\'ab\'>text</td>` ... i added `stripslashes()` where we added the htmlspecial chars `return stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($value));` and it's not showing the slashes anymore on the page but its being added in the database... do u have any idea how to avoid these slashes from being posted in the database?

Comment: @Meh This is obviously becaouse of using the method `magic_quote()` through all the 'page' script. Look at it what id does - I guess it is calling `addslashes` ro something similar. You should avoid of this calls - if You are using MySQL You should escape the data using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: i removed my comment to check ur answer first and i got 2 solutions:
1)i added stripslahes instead of htmlspecialchars in the second code u gave me and it workd `$strUpdate = "UPDATE $this->tablename set $value=".stripslashes(magic_quote($nt))." $updWhere Limit 1";`
2)as u said.. i searched for `addslashes($value)` and removed the addslashes code and it works... ok that's it Thanks alot :)